# Derived/metadata about logs in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

There has to be a lean way to do this:

Dataframe

```
t, ID
700, 1
900, 1
1000, 1
1100, 1
300, 2
100, 3
200, 3
```

Expected Result:

```
elapsed, visits, 1/f, ID
400, 4, 100, 1
0, 1, 0, 2
100, 2, 50, 3
```

Is it using `groupby`? `resample`? should I make an ID `index`?

Comment: What is the `1/f` column?

Comment: @korem the average_time_between_visits, ie, elapsed/visits. `f` is just frequency

Comment: You're going to have to edit your question, at the moment it's terribly unclear and not going to get answered anytime soon as it's guess work at this stage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [88]: result = df.groupby(['ID'])['t'].agg(['min', 'max', 'count'])

In [89]: result['elapsed'] = result['max']-result['min']

In [90]: result['1/f'] = result['elapsed']/result['count']

In [91]: result = result[['elapsed','count', '1/f']].rename(columns={'count':'visits'})

In [92]: result = result.reset_index()

In [93]: result
Out[93]: 
   ID  elapsed  visits  1/f
0   1      400       4  100
1   2        0       1    0
2   3      100       2   50
```

Comment: that's insanely quick and super high qualify of guessing!